# Why my TextClock didnt display value

Tags: android

Why my tv1(TextView) cannot display any value from my `TextClock`? Is there any typo?,

Here is the code of image

[image: error code]

```
TextClock time = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.bgclock);
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

String hour = time.getText().toString();
tv1.setText(hour);
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: `time.getText()` will be an empty string unless you put something in the XML

Comment: hmmm, if i want to get hour value from TextClock time what should i use, is there any code else getText?

Comment: Did you try to read the documentation?

Comment: what is the documentation?

Comment: The API that clearly describes all the methods? Read it. Bookmark it. Always have it open when developing anything Android... https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative way, that's more complicated, but it gets the actual value of the TextClock's text once it has been laid out in the view, using a ViewTreeObserver.

Be aware that cricket_007's responses will also work, it comes down to what you are trying to achieve and how you want to get there.

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/layout_text_clock"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="se.ifthenel.android.aclock.MainActivity">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text_time_label"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Time here!"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <TextClock
      android:id="@+id/text_clock"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/text_time_label"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextClock;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_text_clock);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
      @Override
      public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Stop listening to the ViewtreeObserver from now on
        layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        TextView textLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_time_label);
        TextClock textClock = (TextClock) findViewById(R.id.text_clock);
        String hour = textClock.getText().toString();
        textLabel.setText(hour);

      }
    });

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you can use `getText()` is because a `TextClock` is a `TextView`, but that doesn't mean that is how you get the actual string value of it.

Unclear what value you want, but these should work.

```
String hour = time.getFormat12Hour();
tv1.setText(hour);
```

Or

```
String hour = time.getFormat24Hour();
tv1.setText(hour);
```

Or (preferably)

```
tv1.setText(time.is24HourModeEnabled() ? 
    time.getFormat24Hour() : time.getFormat12Hour());
```

---

Alternatively, if you want the time, `SimpleDateFormat` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague actually. I didn't get what you mean by can not display.However I guess your problem is you are getting an empty string because you called it too early.In that case, try this :

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompactActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextClock;
import android.widget.Textview;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompactActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    ViewTreeObserver obs = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    }
            else {
                            obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                    }
                    TextClock time=(TextClock)findViewById(R.id.bgclock);
            TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            String hour=time.getText().toString();
            tv1.setText(hour);
                }

    });
}
```